# Selenium XPATH how to get text from Span tag underneath the input id tag

Tags: python-2.7, selenium, xpath, selenium-webdriver

I have the following html snippet:

```
<div>
    <span class="gwt-InlineLabel myinlineblock" style="display: none;" aria-hidden="true">Go to row</span>
    <input id="data_configuration_view_preview_ib_row" class="gwt-IntegerBox marginleft red" type="text" size="8"/>
    <span class="gwt-InlineLabel error myinlineblock marginleft" style="width: 7ex;" aria-hidden="false">Error!</span>
</div>
```

I am trying to locate the text Error!

I start from the input id tag as that has an ID.  I am not able to go down to the span tag which has the text Error!

My xpath to start from the id is:

```
//input[@id="data_configuration_view_preview_ib_row"]
```

I have tried:

```
//input[@id="data_configuration_view_preview_ib_row"]/span[contains(text(), "Error!")]
```

What CSS or XPath can I use to locate the text Error!?

I have managed to locate the element with the following Xpath:

```
//input[@id="data_configuration_view_preview_ib_row"]//following-sibling::span[contains(text(), "Error!")]
```

Thanks, Riaz

Comment: have you tried this as xpath;  //span[text()='Error! '] ????

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `cssSelector` as :

- using with `error` class

  ```
  span.error
  ```
- using with id `data_configuration_view_preview_ib_row`

  ```
  #data_configuration_view_preview_ib_row + span.error
  ```

OR you can use `xpath` as :

- using with `error` class

  ```
  //span[contains(@class, 'error')]
  ```
- using with `preceding` id `data_configuration_view_preview_ib_row`

  ```
  //span[preceding::*[@id = 'data_configuration_view_preview_ib_row']]
  ```
- using with `preceding-sibling` id `data_configuration_view_preview_ib_row`

  ```
  //span[preceding-sibling::*[@id = 'data_configuration_view_preview_ib_row']]
  ```

Hope it helps..:)

Answer (score 1):

Use the axis `following-sibling` to get the next element on the same level:

```
//input[@id="data_configuration_view_preview_ib_row"]/following-sibling::span
```

You could also use a CSS selector:

```
#data_configuration_view_preview_ib_row + span
```